# How To Get App Path and Read Text File Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xap, isolatedstorage

My Question is very simple...I hope.

1. I want to get the path of app built in Windows Phone 7.
2. How to Read TEXT File that is placed in BIN folder of the project.

Regards;

Zeeshan Ahmed Khan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use

```
Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(_filePath, UriKind.Relative));
```

where _filePath is the Path to your File without a preceding '/', like "bin/file.txt".

Comment: @KhanZeeshan If this worked for you I'm guessing you set _Build Action_ to _Resource_ for the text file.

Comment: No I just set Build Action to "Content"

Comment: Glad I could help.
For further information check this MSDN entry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978(VS.92).aspx
In there, they load content from the resource stream and write it into the isolated storage (low half of the entry).